# Adding a new line between itemized lines

Tags: indentation, enumerate

I'm having a problem trying to format my homework in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

....
\begin{enumerate}
\item Exercise 1.... 
\item Given $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, ....
\begin{enumerate}
\item Because .... it follows that ....
Given another $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, \ x\longmapsto \sqrt{...}$
\item Because .... it follows that ....
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Now, I would like the second "Given" function to be aligned the same way as the first one.
How do I make this happen, while still having the second item labeled with (b)?

so what I would like to get is something like:

```
1.) ....
2.) Given f...
     (a) .....
    Given g...
     (b) .....
```

And what I get now is:

```
1.) ....
2.) Given f...
     (a) .....
         Given g...
     (b) .....
```

Comment: +1 for doing your math homework in LaTeX and asking for help here. +1 to your instructor for allowing (or requiring) this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd invite you to review your schema to see if this is really what you want; interrupting a list like this usually is a signal of not the best design choice. Perhaps you can find another way to present the information?

That being said, one option using the `resume` option from [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Exercise 1.... 
\item Given $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{enumerate}
\item Because .... it follows that ....
\end{enumerate}
Given another $h\colon\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$,
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Because .... it follows that ....
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `enumitem` you can manually adjust the counter:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Exercise 1.... 
\item Given $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{enumerate}
\item Because .... it follows that ....
\end{enumerate}
Given another $h\colon\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$,
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumii}{1}
\item Because .... it follows that ....
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

or save it at the end of the first list and then use the value to step it in the second.

By the way, to separate the function name from its domain, codomain, you should use `\colon` and not `:` (there's a different in the horizontal spacing); no need for `\longmapsto`; use `\mapsto`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply issuing a `\par` command will push the required statement one line down. But then, you will have two distances you should get rid of; the `\leftmargin` and the `\listparindent` of the current list. So, naturally, you can add this:

```
\par\hspace{\dimexpr-\leftmargin-\listparindent}
```

so that your statement can have the same alignment as the previous one. To be honest, I agree with @GonzaloMedina on the idea of choosing a better design.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip,amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}    

\begin{enumerate}
\item Exercise 1 ...
\item Given $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, ...
\begin{enumerate}
\item Because ... it follows that ... \par\hspace{\dimexpr-\leftmargin-\listparindent}
Given another $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, \ x\longmapsto \sqrt{...}$
\item Because ... it follows that ...
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```